# Zend Framework Create Custom View Helper?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-view

I have tried multiple fixes but none have worked.
 I am getting this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Loader_PluginLoader_Exception'
>   with message 'Plugin by name 'AddCss' was not found in the registry;
>   used paths: Zend_View_Helper_:
>   Zend/View/Helper/:/Users/cgunnels/dev/git/rove-git/application/views/helpers/'
>   in
>   /usr/local/zend/share/ZendFramework/library/Zend/Loader/PluginLoader.php:412
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /usr/local/zend/share/ZendFramework/library/Zend/View/Abstract.php(1182):
>   Zend_Loader_PluginLoader->load('AddCss') #1
>   /usr/local/zend/share/ZendFramework/library/Zend/View/Abstract.php(618):
>   Zend_View_Abstract->_getPlugin('helper', 'addCss') #2
>   /usr/local/zend/share/ZendFramework/library/Zend/View/Abstract.php(344):
>   Zend_View_Abstract->getHelper('addCss') #3
>   /Users/cgunnels/dev/git/rove-git/application/layouts/scripts/layout.phtml(6):
>   Zend_View_Abstract->__call('addCss', Array) #4
>   /Users/cgunnels/dev/git/rove-git/application/layouts/scripts/layout.phtml(6):
>   Zend_View->addCss(Array) #5
>   /usr/local/zend/share/ZendFramework/library/Zend/View.php(108):
>   include('/Users/cgunnels...') #6 /usr in
>   /usr/local/zend/share/ZendFramework/library/Zend/Controller/Plugin/Broker.php
>   on line 336

this is my class:

```
 class Zend_View_Helper_Css extends Zend_View_Helper_Abstract {
      public function css() {
        die("test");
      }
    }
```

I followed the instructions on this page http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.helpers.html and it doesn't work.

I also added this to my application.ini:

```
resources.view.helperPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/views/helpers"
```

Please help me out, thanks

Comment: in my layout I am using this <?php $this->css(); ?>

Comment: I fixed it. So the filename was CssHelper.php I changed it to Css.php and it worked.

Comment: Please add your solution as an answer below and accept it later. Yes that works and yes, that's useful to mark the question as solved. Thank your for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

answer provided by author:

> I fixed it. So the filename was CssHelper.php I changed it to Css.php
>   and it worked. – chris gunnels

Comment: it cant work! he's calling it by a wrong name -  'Plugin by name **'AddCss'** was not found in the registry;